# Using one cell to sum multiple sets created by splitting one other cell (presumably using ARRAYFORMULA)

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I run the clock-in, clock-out system at my organization and currently we use a custom function to determine the total times people work based on their punches.

For example, if a user's entries for a day are: `11 AM - 12PM, 1 PM-2 PM`

The custom function I've written will output : `2`

However, we have run into some problems using the custom function (such as code doesn't always copy between Google Sheets when making copies, and custom functions just sometimes randomly stop working). These can usually be resolved with human intervention, but that costs time and money and we have 1500+ part time staff getting their time approved across 20+ sheets that want to get paid on time.

Thus, I've been working on a non-custom function to sum the sets of times in a single cell.

Summing one set of times is fairly trivial:
`11 AM - 12 PM`

Using the formula `minus(index(split($A2,"-"),1,2),index(split($A2,"-"),1,1))*24`

We get `1`.

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get multiple sets of times to sum without explicitly typing the function multiple times. My intuition is that the solution will use ARRAYFORMULA, but thus far I can only get it to sum the *first* set of times:
`11AM - 12PM, 1 PM - 2 PM`

Formula: `arrayformula(sum(minus(index(split(split($A5,","),"-"),1,2),index(split(split($A5,","),"-"),1,1))*24))`

Result: `1`

We cannot split the times into multiple cells as an intermediate step because of the way the spreadsheet is set up. Even if we could, an employee could theoretically have an infinite number of sets of times (something like 5 would be a realistic theoretical cap, but still... we don't want to have 4 extra columns that are almost never used).

Here is a **view-only** Google Sheet with some examples. Feel free to **make a copy** and play with your copy as much as you like.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gVZ09OT_PMSCWocIYW9FM9QfEmLVUI1-LWu1b8HsOsQ/

Comment: 1) Would you please explain **how** employees “punch” in and out? 2) Do the 20+ sheets relate to 20+ work places? 3) do employees punch in/out at a central location, or a location related to the context of a sheet? 4) does the working day cross over midnight? That is, do any shifts or breaks start before midnight and end after midnight?

Comment: (1) They submit a Google form. A script then converts the form submissions into a human-readable spreadsheet. (2) It's 20+ supervisors, one sheet per supervisor, but generally each supervisor oversees one location, yes. (3) Employees find themselves in the form by first selecting their location, so yes, that is known. (4) We assume it does not. If that were to happen for any reason, we would expect staff to clock out at 11:59 PM and clock back in at 12 AM, even if only nominally.

Comment: so why not write a query that accesses the Response Sheets. And count the number of instances per employee for a given date. You could also create the the shift times. FWIW, how do you get the "Starting Times" at the moment?

Comment: BTW, I notice row Rows, 2 & 3 & 5 have AM/PM delimiters, but the other rows have integers. Except cell B4 which is a weird combination of both.

Comment: The script that puts times in a nicely formatted spreadsheet for supervisors to review, edit, and approve is essentially that query. We cannot simply reference the times because we need a copy of what was submitted by staff, but supervisors also need to be able to edit their version on the fly and see those edits in real time. Starting times are just the times staff submitted the form. B4 is just to demonstrate what the value of B5 *should* be. It is not used in the final product.

Answer (score 1):

This works in [this editable copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EL1lfzAH0C227KKqm_yb5gYjJvM8DzeTONs0dlF3FDc/edit#gid=0)...

```
=MAP(A1:A,LAMBDA(val,IF(val=A1,"Ending Value",IF(val="",,LET(times,IF(REGEXMATCH(val,":"),SPLIT(val,","),SPLIT(val,";")),REDUCE(0,times,LAMBDA(a,c,a+IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(SPLIT(c,"-"),{-24,24}),SUMPRODUCT(SPLIT(c,","),{-1,1})))))))))
```

[image]